# Printing linked text based on user input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display text that links to a website based on user input and when an action button is pressed so it looks like this:

[image]

The linked text goes to the cran documentation. Here's what I have so far.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = 'package',
              label = 'Enter package name:'),

    actionButton("webpage", "View Webpage"),
    
    hr(),
    
    textOutput("site",container=span),

  ),
  mainPanel()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  url <- eventReactive(input$webpage, {
    paste0('selected pakcage: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/',
                                    input$package,'/index.html')
  })
  
  output$site <- renderText({url()})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I format it so that the package the user enters will be displayed as a linked text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one method is to change your `textOutput` to
`htmlOutput("site",container=span)`
then, try this server

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  url <- eventReactive(input$webpage, {
    paste0('https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/',
           input$package,'/index.html')
  })
  output$site <- renderUI(a(input$package, target="_blank", # site link
             href = url()
             ))
}
```

see [this page](https://community.rstudio.com/t/hyperlink-portion-of-text-in-shiny-server-text-block/67328/2) for more info